# ¿Cómo recuperar los datos de un ID con reportlab?

Tags: python, django, reportlab

Quiero imprimir los datos de un solo ID, pero me sale error:

Código **views.py**:

```
class Reporte(View):

    def cabecera(self,pdf):
        escudo_bolivia = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/images/escudobo.png'     
        pdf.drawImage(escudo_bolivia, 380, 750, 120, 90,preserveAspectRatio=True) 

    def datos(self, pk):
        query = corresp_ext.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, str(query.id))
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, query.name)
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, query.cantidad)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="reporteExterno.pdf"'        
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(response)
        self.cabecera(pdf)      
        self.datos(pk)
        pdf.showPage()
        pdf.save()  
        return response
```

Codigo **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^reporte/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Reporte.as_view(), name='reporte')
```

Código **informe.html**:

```
<a href="{% url 'inventario:reporte' inventario.id %}"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimir</a>
```

Al momento de dar el click al botón de imprimir me sale este error:

```
NameError at /inventario/reporte/3/

global name 'pk' is not defined
```

El error me sobre sale sobre todo en esta línea de código:

```
self.datos(pk)
```

Comment: De algún modo, el argumento `pk` tiene que llegar al método `get` para acceder a él. Seguramente esté en el diccionario `kwargs`: `pk = kwargs.get("pk", None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La definición de tu URL es correcta pero para poder obtener el ID o PK que se ha mandado tienes que hacerlo a través de `self.kwargs` (no confundir con `**kwargs`):

```
pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
```

Por lo tanto, tu vista debería ser:

```
class Reporte(View):

    def cabecera(self,pdf):
        escudo_bolivia = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/images/escudobo.png'     
        pdf.drawImage(escudo_bolivia, 380, 750, 120, 90,preserveAspectRatio=True) 

    def datos(self, pk):
        query = corresp_ext.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, str(query.id))
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, query.name)
        pdf.drawString(cx+470, cy+10, query.cantidad)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Obtener el PK
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="reporteExterno.pdf"'        
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(response)
        self.cabecera(pdf)      
        self.datos(pk) # <--- acá recién la usas
        pdf.showPage()
        pdf.save()  
        return response
```

De ahí el error del tipo `NameError` que ocurre cuando usas una variable que no ha sido definida.

**Nota:** No olvides validar que `pk` sea un entero ya que podría darte algún error si se pasan IDs inválidos como `xxx` o `yyy`.

Comment: oooh muchas gracias si ya vi que no me sale error en eso, ya me recupera el id, pero me salio un error de lo que no es un nombre global de "pdf",( global name 'pdf' is not defined), disculpa que te moleste con esto, pero para que me reconozca como una variable global debería de sacarlo fuera de los def????

Comment: YA NO YA NO XD ya lo corregí ya me da todo gracias por tu ayuda mil gracias enserio , te lo agradezco un montón no sabes cuanto muchas muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Lun no hay problema. No olvides aceptar la pregunta ya que de otra forma se queda como abierta.